# Does Exchange Server store out-of-office/automatic replies in a human-readable form on the filesystem when set?

Tags: windows, email, exchange

When setting an out-of-office/automatic reply on a mailbox, there are several ways to then either edit or disable the reply. Out of interest, is the text for these automatic replies stored in a file or similar on the filesystem of the machine that Exchange is running on?

Comment: That's oddly specific. What do you intend to do? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you configure OOF/Automatic reply for your mailbox? **Automatic Replies** settings in **Account Information**  in Outlook?

If so, we could run the following command to preview the OOF settings configured by Outlook:

```
Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity "<MailboxIdentity>" | Select-Object AutoReplyState, StartTime, EndTime, ExternalMessage, InternalMessage
```

( If the `AutoReplyState` showed `Enabled`, the OOF settings were configured without a specific period. If it showed `Scheduled`, the OOF settings were configured with a specific period. )

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And you could add a cmdlet behind the above command to export the external/internal OOF message to a .html file for preview:

```
Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity "<MailboxIdentity>" | Select-Object ExternalMessage, InternalMessage | Export-Csv C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\OOFMessage.html
```

[image]